# How to grant VM access to Key Vault in the same ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template

I'm attempting to create an ARM-template capable of provisioning a VM **AND** a Key Vault. The VM identity is set to type "SystemAssigned". See code snippet below:

```
        ...
        "name": "[variables('VM1')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
        "identity": { 
            "type": "SystemAssigned"
        },
        "apiVersion": "2019-07-01",
        ...
```

I want to be able to give the VM permissions to access the secrets in the Vault. For this is need to retrieve the `tenantID` and `ObjectID` for `accessPolicies`. For the tenantID I'm using:

`"tenantId":  "[subscription().tenantId]",`

Is there a similar way to reference the ObjectID for a VM that is being created in the same template?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a reference to get to the Managed Service Identity's object id (Principal Id) of the VM to assign access to KeyVault. [See the documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/qs-configure-template-windows-vm).

I see KeyVault wants the TenantID and the Object ID.

The tenant you should already have in the template 
`"tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]"`

and the ObjectID is the PrincipalId as shown in the docs linked and example below.

```
{
    "apiVersion": "2017-09-01",
    "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments",
    "name": "[parameters('rbacGuid')]",
    "properties": {
        "roleDefinitionId": "[variables(parameters('builtInRoleType'))]",
        "principalId": "[reference(variables('vmResourceId'), '2017-12-01', 'Full').identity.principalId]",
        "scope": "[resourceGroup().id]"
    },
     "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', parameters('vmName'))]"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Sometimes the naming can get a bit confusing, it's cleaned up a bit lately but at one point, Principal Id, Object Id and Application Id were more or less used interchangeably.